# How exactly does redirection prevent form resubmission?

Tags: php, redirect

When a user logs in and is redirected to member's page then logs out wouldn't clicking the back button make the form data resubmit, check that it's ok and redirect again? When this happens the user is not able to view the member's page again because it checks for a session variable but re-sending all the information with a page refresh or the back button would make them log in again so even though this system works perfectly, what is the reason below the hood that makes it work?

I have created log in systems that redirect the user if the information is correct and this solves the problem of page refreshes and back button re-log ins. I just don't understand how, and why this works.

All answers are very appreciated.

***For all those who share this same question. I think the reason is POST requests are not cached so no data is re-sent.

Comment: Any code to show us.?

Comment: Simple thought: Browsers don't keep a history of all the resources (cookies, sessions, etc).

Comment: clicking the back button is just javascript back and not exactly form submission

Comment: The browser does send the data again, doesn't it?

Comment: If you navigate back to a page that was the server answer to a POST request, then the browser is supposed to ask you if you want to send that same POST data again. If you _redirect_ in the server response to a POST request, then the client will request the new URL via GET – and places that GET request in its history, “overwriting” the POST request entry in the history. So if that’s been done and you navigate back afterwards, then it’s only the GET request that the browser “goes back to”, and so no form data is send again.

Comment: Btw., wikipedia has an article on that pattern: [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Beautifully replied CBroe, now I understand. Very appreciated.